# the least value for :$\frac{a}{b^3+54}+\frac{b}{c^3+54}+\frac{c}{a^3+54}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

For every $a,b,c$ non-negative real number such that:$a+b+c=1$ how to find the least value for :

$$\frac{a}{b^3+54}+\frac{b}{c^3+54}+\frac{c}{a^3+54}$$

Comment: Do you mean to have some constraint on $a+b+c$? Otherwise $a=b=c=0$ clearly is a minimum.

Comment: @OP do you know the Lagrange Multiplier method?

Comment: @Clayton  $a+b+c=1$

Comment: if we will consider case $a\le b \le c$, then  $(a,b,c)\approx (0,0.251454,0.748546)$. Exactly: $a=0$; $b = 1- c$; $c$ is positive root of equation $c^4+54\cdot 4c - 54 \cdot 3 = 0$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Both you and the site would benefit if you would consider [registering your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account).

Comment: The least value for the given formula must be greater than 9/487, but this boundary doesn't help here at all, of course.

Comment: May Lagrange multiplier work?? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle g(x,y,z)=\frac{x}{y^3+54}+\frac{y}{z^3+54}+\frac{z}{x^3+54}$.

If we consider $g(a,b,1-(a+b))$ we can use $\partial_ag=0$ and $\partial_bg=0$ to numerically find 
 the following critical points (up to cyclic permutation): $$\begin{array}{lll|l}
 \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{g(a,b,c)} \\ \hline
 1.20836 & -0.608416 & 0.400057 & 0.0183912 \\
 0.51624 & 0.32016 & 0.1636 & 0.0185045 \\
 0.333333 & 0.333333 & 0.333333 & 0.0185058 \\
 4.69649 & -0.929554 & -2.76694 & 0.0424017\\
\end{array}$$
so in the region $a,b,1-(a+b)> 0$ it seems the minimum value is $\leq 0.0185045$.  Now, for the boundaries, we use (w.l.o.g) $g(0,b,1-b)$.  This has a minimum at $b=0.251454$ where $g(0,b,1-b)=0.0184826$. We also have to check So this seems to be the minimum value of $g(a,b,c)$ subject to $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c\geq 0$.

I tried to use Lagrange  multipliers to get an exact algebraic solution, but the expressions were much too complicated (i.e. not solvable by radicals). I suspect there is no pretty closed form expression.

*EDIT*: By the way, here is a plot of $g(x,y,1-(x+y))$ in the region $x,y,1-(x+y)\geq 0$ (with critical points highlighted in blue and the minima highlighted in red):

[image: Plot of g(x,y,1-(x+y)) on x,y,1-(x+y) >= 0]

Comment: After a laborious process I get the same.+1

Comment: @AlexanderGruber You get 0.0184826 with a = 0.748545, b = 0, c = 0.251455 which is basically what you got too I think.

Comment: @lip1 Indeed, that is a cyclic permutation of the boundary solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said non-negative, I am going to assume that zero is allowed in which case I found a minimum value of 0.0184826 achieved at $a=0, b=0.748545, c=0.251455$ up to their cyclic permutations.

After posting this I see that Oleg567 pointed to this solution already. Furthermore, if you want all $a,b,c$ to be strictly positive then <strike>it looks like the minimum is indeed at 0.0185045</strike> although the values for $a,b,c$ where it is achieved are not unique. In addition to Alexander Gruber and daniel's answer, I found $a=0.530893, b=0.335498, c=0.133609$.

Comment: "Furthermore, if you want all $a,b,c$ to be strictly positive then it looks like the minimum is indeed at $0.0185045$..." This is false, and in fact, you showed it was false by finding a smaller value on the boundary.  Continuity tells us that in any very small ball around your boundary point, we can find a smaller value than $0.0185045$.   The function actually has **no** global minimum on $a+b+c=1$, $a,b,c>0$.

Comment: Yep you are right, this was done in two separate parts and of course the post was edited without any thought at all. :-) If I would have only taken five seconds longer...